# perl regexp problem

Tags: regex, perl

i have these kind of lines

object1:object2:object3:rest of the line

I want a regular expression for extracting each text until the colon.

In this case I need:

$1= object1
$2= object2
$3= object3
$4= rest of the line

I tried with this:

> `$_ =~ m/\(.*\):\(.*\):\(.*\):\(.*\)/i`

but it seems to not work.

where am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the `\`'s:

```
$_ =~ m/(.*?):(.*?):(.*?):(.*)/i
```

Also, the `i` (case-insensitive matching) is redundant since you have no characters in your regex as well as the `m` which allows you to choose a different regex boundary character other than `/`. You also don't need the `$_ =~` as Perl defaults to `$_`. So you can reduce it to:

```
/(.*):(.*):(.*):(.*)/
```

http://ideone.com/TLepM

Comment: Perfect but I found an other problem: if the line is

Comment: You may want to make the first three non-greedy - if there are colons in the "rest of the line", you may not end up with what you expect.

Comment: @Kerby82 Yup, noticed that as well thanks though.
@Graeme Perrow Edited thanks.

Comment: @Kerby82: Add a `?`, so you have `/(.*?):(.*?):(.*?):(.*)/`

Comment: Having said all that, @pax is right: `split` is what you should be using here.

Comment: @Graeme Perrow thanks! now it works! My requirements it's not to use split just regexp! This is just for learning better regex! I know that with split is easy and better :-)

Answer (score 4):

Why are you using a regex for this when [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) does exactly what you want?

```
$x = "object1:object2:object3:rest of the line";
@x = split (":", $x);
foreach $s (@x) {
        print "$s\n";
}
```

This outputs:

```
object1
object2
object3
rest of the line
```

If you want to limit yourself to four fields regardless of the number of colons, you can use:

```
$x = "object1:object2:object3:rest of the line with a : character";
@x = split (":", $x, 4);
foreach $s (@x) {
        print "$s\n";
}
```

which outputs:

```
object1
object2
object3
rest of the line with a : character
```

Comment: +1 This is the better way. But can you add the count of 4 tokens like @FM has in his answer.

Comment: Sorry @paxdiablo but I can't use split :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
my @objects = split ':', $data_line, 4;
```